# ViewController Not redirect Other View Controller

Tags: iphone, swift

In My App I get a PushNotification and touch notification to open a specific ViewController. All Notification are received and opens view controllers. Apart from one View controller that does not open but throws this type of error

This is my Code

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let nextVCDentist : UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DentistProfileViewCtr") as! DentistProfileViewCtr

let navigation : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextVCDentist)

let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            app.window?.rootViewController = navigation
```

And this is the error

> Failed to set (colorEmpty) user defined inspected property on (Cosmos.CosmosView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key colorEmpty.
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The error tells you that you are trying to access a property called `colorEmpty` on something of type `CosmosView`. So have a look in your code and see if you try to set a `colorEmpty` property somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess, judging from the error message: you added a `@IBInspectable` property called `colorEmpty` in `CosmosView`, and then deleted it, but just in code.

Try to open `CosmosView` in the interface builder, if you still see the property under **User Defined Runtime Attributes**, remove it and you should be good to go :)

Comment: @IbInspectable ColorEmpty Property delet..then...Retriving other error..like..fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value